# FadeIn a medida que o navegador desce

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um probleminha, acho que é mais lógica mesmo. É o seguinte estou tentando fazer aquele efeito de quando vou rolando o site para baixo o conteúdo vai aparecendo.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(".j_show").offset().top) {
        $(".j_show").each(function () {
        $(this).delay("1000").fadeIn("2000");
      });
    }
});
});
```

A classe .j_show é a do conteúdo, e a vários conteúdo com essa classe. O problema é que quando `($(window).scrollTop() >= $(".j_show").offset().top)` chega na altura que é para dá o `fadeIn`, dá, mais aparece é todos que estão com a classe, e não e isso que eu quero, quero que o `fadeIn` execute conteúdo por conteúdo dependendo da altura.

ps: já tentei sem a função `each`, mais logicamente da no mesmo.

‪#‎help‬

Answer (score 0):

Tenta essa lógica.

```
   $('.j_show').each(function(){
        var fade = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (fade < topOfWindow + 650) {
            $(this).delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Vai não cara. Tá complicado. As vezes é besteira, mais não consigo imagina em uma lógica que de certo. Arrisca outra?